# Organizing a report based on new and removed entries in a particular field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a simple report which pulls records under a given criteria. It only pulls:

```
ID | Name | PI | Address | Phone
```

I need to separate this into four separate reports; records added, removed records, other changes and no changes.

If a record has been added, that means that the field PI did not exact on the last run of the report. If it's removed, I know that means it was on the last report but not this one. Other changes classify any edits to Name, Address or Phone.

So if I have two of these reports, Original and New, what queries would accomplish this? Both reports have the same fields above.

I've attempted to run a union using a WHERE NOT EXISTS clause among other things, but I just can't get the syntax right.

Answer (score 0):

What is the unique identifier of each record that you can use to compare between Original and New reports? I would have normally guessed `ID`, but then you state:

> If a record has been added, that means that the field PI did not exact
>   on the last run of the report.

(should "exact" have been "exist"?). Anyway, let's assume it's the `ID` field - if it is in fact the `PI` field then just change `ID` to `PI` in all the JOIN clauses below.

New records added:

```
SELECT n.* FROM [NEW] n LEFT JOIN [ORIGINAL] o ON n.ID = o.ID WHERE o.ID IS NULL
```

Records deleted:

```
SELECT o.* FROM [ORIGINAL] o LEFT JOIN [NEW] n ON n.ID = o.ID WHERE n.ID IS NULL
```

Records changed:

```
SELECT o.ID, o.PI, o.Name Orig_Name, n.Name New_Name, 
    o.Address Orig_Address, n.Address New_Address, 
    o.Phone Orig_Phone, n.Phone New_Phone
FROM [ORIGINAL] o INNER JOIN [NEW] n ON o.ID = n.ID
WHERE o.Name <> n.Name OR o.Address <> n.Address OR o.Phone <> n.Phone
```

Records not changed:

```
SELECT o.ID, o.PI, o.Name, o.Address, o.Phone
FROM [ORIGINAL] o INNER JOIN [NEW] n ON o.ID = n.ID
WHERE o.Name = n.Name AND o.Address = n.Address AND o.Phone = n.Phone
```